# Htaccess 301 Redirect Issue With External Domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Basically I am using a registrar to 301 redirect a domain to a different domain [example.org] and then I am trying to redirect some of the inner pages as well by using htaccess on [example.org]

**problem 1:** I'm trying to redirect

> es/notice.php?file=news.php

to

> es/

but even though the redirection works, now it appears as

> es/?file=news.php

**problem 2:** the redirection of individual pages (e.x; len.php to /es/) still doesn't work, shows a 404

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteEngine On

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^/?pricing$ http://example.org/buy-stuff [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?stuff-tour$ http://example.org/stuff-stuff-tour [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?fr/stuff-tour$ http://example.org/stuff-stuff-tour [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?es/notice.php$ http://example.org/es/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?len.php$ http://example.org/es/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?latest-blog-posts$ http://example.org/blog [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?por/(.*)$ http://example.org/es/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?nl/(.*)$ http://example.org/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?it/(.*)$ http://example.org/ [R=301,L]

#ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$  $1/$2.htm [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ $1.htm [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f  
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z\-]+)$  $1.htm

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<FILES .htaccess>
order allow,deny 
deny from all
</FILES>

Options -Indexes 
IndexIgnore *.zip *.txt
```

Comment: `es/?select=es&file=news.php` cannot be made from`es/notice.php` with just the above rules. There are other rules or something else is also redirecting your requests.

Comment: @SteveE. sorry that was a mistake in the post, I corrected it now, please check post again

Comment: Which version of apache are you using? 2.4.x has an option [QSD] that solves problem 1 easily.

Comment: @SteveE. edit okay I fixed that, thanks

Comment: @SteveE. In regard to the second problem, I realized that the only page which doesn't redirect is the es/notice.php for some odd reason. The only difference between that page and the other which works (len.php) is that this one has a subdir (es/file.php)